# What's the difference between `systemctl stop` and `systemctl kill`?

Tags: systemd

What's the difference between `systemctl stop` and `systemctl kill`?

`systemctl kill` supports sending a custom signal to the process, e.g. `-9` (SIGKILL) instead of `-15` (SIGTERM). So, is the only difference that `systemctl kill` is a more general version of `systemctl stop`, i.e. `systemctl stop` always sends `-15` (SIGTERM)?

As an example, `systemctl stop` and `systemctl kill` have the same result for `ssh.service` (`sshd`):

`systemctl stop`:

```
$ systemctl stop sshd
$ systemctl status sshd
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2021-11-08 09:09:32 CET; 1s ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
  Process: 2086153 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2086154 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2086154 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

`systemctl kill`:

```
$ systemctl kill sshd
$ systemctl status sshd
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2021-11-08 09:10:15 CET; 1s ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
  Process: 2086486 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2086487 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2086487 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Comment: There are some additional details (albeit not _that_ detailed) under `man systemctl` that may help you find the answer to your question.

Answer (score 12):

`systemctl kill` is pretty similar to `kill` in that it simply sends a signal (default=SIGTERM).  The main difference between `kill` and `systemctl kill` is you can specify a unit instead of a PID and systemd understands which processes you want to send that signal to.

On the otherhand `systemctl stop` will stop one or more units specified on the command line.  First `systemd` will run any `ExecStop=` lines (if any). If any processes remain, handle these using `KillMode=` rules.  After that, it sends `SIGTERM` (can be changed with `KillSignal=`).  If `SendSIGHUP=` is set, it will send SIGHUP immediately after that.  If the process doesn't handle SIGTERM well and fails to stop within 90s (can be changed with `TimeoutStopSec=`), then send SIGKILL (can be changed with `FinalKillSignal=`).  In addition, if `KillMode=control-group` (default), then any child processes will also be killed.

So you can see that `systemctl kill` simply sends a signal.  That may stop a unit, but systemd does not ensure that happens.  Instead `systemctl stop` WILL stop a unit.

---

`systemctl kill` is equivalent to `systemctl stop` assuming:

1. There is no `ExecStop=`
2. `KillSignal=` in the unit file is equal to `--signal=`.
3. The unit is guaranteed to respond to the first signal (no hanging) and does not need a followup.
4. `KillMode=` is not set, or is equal to `process`.

---

One thing special about sshd.service is it contains:

```
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
```

In this case, you may ask:  What's the different between these two commands:

```
# systemctl reload sshd
# systemctl kill --signal=SIGHUP --kill-who=sshd.service
```

While they are almost the same, the difference is quite obvious here... `reload` calls `/usr/sbin/sshd -t` before the signal.

---

Another special thing about sshd.service is it contains `KillMode=process`.  This makes the `systemctl kill` and `systemctl stop` a little closer as orphaned child processes will not be cleaned up by systemd.  By default `KillMode=control-group` will cause systemd to clean up all orphaned child processes

Comment: Good explaination.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual, `kill`:

> `kill` PATTERN...
> Send a signal to one or more **processes** of the unit. Use `--kill-who=` to select which process to kill. Use `--signal=` to select the signal to send.

And `stop`:

> `stop` PATTERN...
> Stop (deactivate) one or more **units** specified on the command line.

So `kill` will kill processes of a spefic unit, while `stop` will stop specified units.

You can see the difference here:

```
# theres's no process killed
$ sudo systemctl kill ufw
$ sudo systemctl status ufw
● ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2021-11-08 05:47:44 -03; 18s ago
       Docs: man:ufw(8)
    Process: 48409 ExecStart=/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 48409 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

Hasta                      Acción      Desde
-----                      ------      -----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
...           

$ sudo systemctl restart ufw
$ sudo systemctl stop ufw
$ sudo systemctl status ufw
● ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2021-11-08 05:49:08 -03; 1s ago
       Docs: man:ufw(8)
    Process: 48785 ExecStart=/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 48995 ExecStop=/lib/ufw/ufw-init stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 48785 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Comment: So, is it application specific that `systemctl stop` and `systemctl kill` result in the same behavior for `sshd.service`?

Comment: @Shuzheng If you ran the commands one after another, i.e: `systemctl stop` and *then* `systemctl kill sshd`, the unit is already stopped when executing the latter Could that be the case?

Comment: Nope, I explicitly did `systemctl start` and checked in was running :-) You can try it yourself with `sshd.service`.

Comment: @Shuzheng I think in the case og `sshd`, is that *there's a process called `sshd`*, so that process is killed.

Comment: I don't think so. `sshd.service` is just an alias for `ssh.service`.

Comment: In the code you show it says that it executes `Process: 2086154 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd`. That is not a service, it's an executable.