# I wish to kill a service with a "sytemctl kill logstash.service" but SIGTERM is received by the service, instead of a SIGKILL. How do I send SIGKILL?

Tags: kill, systemctl, sigterm, sigkill

A new *logstash* version I'm using can't stop, attempting to connect to *Elastic* all the time, while it can't (an authentication trouble, I will resolve later).

a `sudo systemctl stop logstash.service` isn't enough to stop it, so I've issued a `sudo systemctl kill logstash.service`.

But it doesn't stop it neither.

a `sudo system status logstash.service` displays:

```
lebihan@debian:~$ sudo systemctl kill logstash.service

lebihan@debian:~$ sudo systemctl status logstash.service
● logstash.service - logstash
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/logstash.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) since Sun 2023-08-20 07:51:21 CEST; 1h 4min ago
   Main PID: 47926 (java)
      Tasks: 176 (limit: 76997)
     Memory: 1.6G
        CPU: 28min 605ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/logstash.service
             └─47926 /usr/share/logstash/jdk/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.security.eg>

août 20 08:55:36 debian logstash[47926]: [2023-08-20T08:55:36,702][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://l>
août 20 08:55:41 debian logstash[47926]: [2023-08-20T08:55:41,704][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://l>
août 20 08:55:42 debian systemd[1]: logstash.service: Sent signal SIGTERM to main process 47926 (java) on client request.
août 20 08:55:42 debian logstash[47926]: [2023-08-20T08:55:42,326][WARN ][logstash.runner          ] SIGTERM received. Shutting down.
août 20 08:55:46 debian logstash[47926]: [2023-08-20T08:55:46,706][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"ht
```

Why isn't my `systemctl kill` sending a SIGKILL event, instead of a SIGTERM?
And how do I send a SIGKILL to my service to force it to stop, with `systemctl`?

Comment: @A.B Thanks. I read your link to another SO question already, but doesn't reply to my problem. How do I kill with a SIGKILL my service if `systemctl kill` doesn't work?

Comment: Are you sure? check about "KillSignal=" and "--signal=" in the answer

Comment: @A.B. Then why don't you answer with that? My problem isn't the difference between systemctl stop and kill, it's to stop a service.

Comment: I agree. It's  done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation about `systemctl kill`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#kill%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6) never tells it will send a `SIGKILL` by default:

> `kill` PATTERN…
>
> Send a UNIX process signal to one or more processes of the unit. Use
> `--kill-whom=` to select which process to send the signal to. **Use
> `--signal=` to select the signal to send**. Combine with
> `--kill-value=` to enqueue a POSIX Realtime Signal with an associated
> value.

Unless told otherwise, `systemctl kill` will use the signal defined in the service.

To actually send a `SIGKILL` to the service *someservice* one should do:

```
systemctl kill --signal=SIGKILL someservice
```

Additional details can be found in [this Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/676576/whats-the-difference-between-systemctl-stop-and-systemctl-kill).

Comment: See also [`systemd.kill(5)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html).